# I found an error can't read properties of main undefined

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I found an error when writing test cases through jest and render my component this takes that the error can't read properties of main undefined.
How to resolve this issue?

```
enter code here
```

describe('Product details test cases', () => {

```
test('product details image must have src and alt', () => {
    render(<ProductDetails />);
    const panadolImg = screen.getByRole('img');
    expect(panadolImg).toHaveAttribute('src', Panadol160Img);
    expect(panadolImg).toHaveAttribute('alt', 'AbocalImg');
});

test('product details sku id', () => {
    render(<ProductDetails />);
    const productSku = screen.getByTestId('sku-id');
    expect(productSku).toMatchSnapshot();  
});

test('product details name of sku', () => {
    render(<ProductDetails />);
    const productName = screen.getByTestId('product-name');
    expect(productName).toMatchSnapshot();  
});
```

});

Comment: Could you share more details about the error stacktrace ? the code you try with a sample  ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
       test('product details name of sku', () => {
           const { getByTestId } = render(<ProductDetails />);
                                      ^
             const productName = getByTestId('product-name');
              expect(productName).toMatchSnapshot();
       });

Comment: I found this error when I render component in my test case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.